# calculation throuh jquery and coldfusion not matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

Working on the ColdFusion Code and Jquery Code, all is working good, but the calculations I am doing in ColdFusion and Jquery are not matching, is there something i am doing wrong.

Here is the ColdFusion Code:

```
quoteLineItemSubTotal = (('#Evaluate("form.quantity_#id#")#' * '#Evaluate("form.normalprice_#id#")#') - '#Evaluate("form.quoteLineItemDiscount_#id#")#' - '#Evaluate("form.itemTax_#id#")#')
```

Here is the jquery Code

```
 $(document).on('keypress keyup keydown change','#quoteLineItemQuantity,#quoteLineItemDiscount,#itemTax,#quoteLineItemPriceUnit',function(e) {
        var qty = $("#quoteLineItemQuantity").val();
        var price = parseFloat($("#quoteLineItemPriceUnit").val());
        var qtyDiscount = parseFloat($("#quoteLineItemDiscount").val()/100);
        var qtyTax = parseFloat($("#itemTax").val()/100);
        var total = parseFloat(qty*price-qtyDiscount-qtyTax).toFixed(2);
        $("#quoteLineItemSubTotal").val(total); 
    });
```

Comment: What results are you getting, and which would you say is correct?

Comment: Also, what are the values of the applicable variables?

Comment: @dan - application variables mean?

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked, but it might help in breaking down the differences.  Try rewriting your CF code this way `quoteLineItemSubTotal = form["quantity_#id#"] * form["normalprice_#id#"] - form["quoteLineItemDiscount_#id#"] - form["itemTax_#id#"]`

Comment: After that, I would suggest writing the individual pieces from CF into the page and the jquery stuff should be logged to the console.  You should be able to figure out where the differences are with each element in your caluculation

Comment: I didn't say application, I said applicable.  One such variable would be the price.

Comment: Check the #Evaluate("form.itemTax_#id#")# and qtyTax are equal. there is a /100 in jQuery code and not in CF code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly happening here. Check the `#Evaluate("form.itemTax_#id#")#` and `qtyTax` are equal. There is a /100 in jQuery code and not in CF code

You used '`#Evaluate("form.itemTax_#id#")#`' straightaway in CF and in jQuery you did var `qtyTax = parseFloat($("#itemTax").val()/100);`

In the case of `qtyDiscount` too you did the same.